# Connect three events in one working function

Tags: javascript, html

I need help with the following - I have a background image and another(small image) on top of that image, and this small image works like a button, when I click on it the background image changes to another image, also when I hover my mouse over this button, this small image should change as well. I have 3 events happening, one for switching the background image(1), one for mouse over(2) and one for mouse out(3). All that is working, but not exactly as I need. On my small button image I have text before/after, when I hover over the button the small image changes from before to after, and that makes sense, I click on it and the background image changes as well, now I need that this small button will show text in reverse - after and when I hover, change to before, but it doesn't happen, I need to connect event 2/3 with event 1, so if I change main/background image, the small button will know when to show before and when after. I have two working functions, each works separately, but I need to somehow connect them into working together:

```
   <div class="container">
    <img src="asset1.jpg" id="getImage">       
    <input type="image" id="image" onclick="switchimage()" onmouseover="setNewImage()" onmouseout="setFinalImage()" src="button3.png">
</div>


<script>
        function switchimage() {
        var Image_Id = document.getElementById('getImage');
        if (Image_Id.src.match("asset1.jpg")) {
            Image_Id.src = "asset2.jpg";
        }
        else {
            Image_Id.src = "asset1.jpg";
        }
    }     
 function setNewImage()
{
    document.getElementById('image').src ="button4.png";
    }

function setFinalImage()
{
    document.getElementById('image').src ="button3.png";
}
</script>
```

Comment: "On my small button image I have text before/after" ??? I see no text

Comment: Because it is image with text on it(button3 and button4) two different images one with word before and one with word after

Comment: basically it is an image that behave like a button

Comment: Are the words "Before" and "After" separate html text elements displayed along side the image or Text that is part of the image pixels?

Comment: right, text is a part of the image not a html text element

Answer (score 0):

So without all the information, I think this is close to what you mean to do:

```js
var asset1img = "https://picsum.photos/id/1000/300/100"
var asset2img = "https://picsum.photos/id/1001/300/100"

var button3img = "https://picsum.photos/id/1003/40/40"
var button4img = "https://picsum.photos/id/1004/40/40"

function switchImage(clickEvent) {
  var span = document.getElementById(clickEvent.target.dataset.targetTxtId);
  span.textContent = (span.textContent === "Before" ? "retfA" : "Before");

  var img = document.getElementById(clickEvent.target.dataset.targetImgId);
  img.src = (img.src === asset1img ? asset2img : asset1img);
}

function setButtonImage(mouseEvent) {
  var button = mouseEvent.target;
  button.src = (button.src === button3img ? button4img : button3img);
}
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.container #buttonContainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  height: 100%;
}

.container #buttonContainer input {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1000/300/100" id="imgImage1">
  <div id="buttonContainer">
    <input type="image" id="imageBtn" 
           onclick="switchImage(event)" 
           data-target-img-id="imgImage1" 
           data-target-txt-id="spnText1"
           onmouseover="setButtonImage(event)"
           onmouseout="setButtonImage(event)"
           src="https://picsum.photos/id/1003/40/40" />
    <span id="spnText1">Before</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! That's what I did, but it is not exactly what I need, the text embedded on the small  image(part of the image). I have one small image with text "before"(1) and one small image with text "after"(2) when I hover over small image it should changed from 1 to 2(and when I move my mouse away come back to 1), but when I click on it,  background image change and here the trick my small image should stay in position 2 when I am away and change to position 1 when I hover over it with mouse, so basically small image depends on  what background image I am showing now and work accordingly.

Comment: I'm not clear by what you mean by position of the small image. do you mean to show the button before the main image and then move it's position when clicked to be displayed after?